# Solve  $x^x=2x$ for $x$, s.t. $x\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> Solve $x^x=2x$ for $x$, such that $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

I'm not sure if the question has a closed form solution.

Comment: This is equivalent to $(x-1)\ln x = \ln 2 $. $2$ works, but I dont know more...

Comment: Note that $2^2=2\times 2$. But there is another solution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem see for a power series solution

Comment: Lagrange inversion theorem is still not able to do this question.

Comment: Another real solution is about $0.346323362278580922$